# Problema con While (mysql_fetch_assoc)

Tags: mysql, while

Hola soy un programador que recién esta empezando y tengo un problema con While, estoy rescatando un dato de una tabla de SQL, hasta ahí todo bien, de hecho si le hago un print_r  antes del While me lo rescata sin ningún problema, pero al momento de pasar por el while no me muestra ningún dato.

este es mi código:

```
            $result = mysql_query($sSQL, $conexion) or die(mysql_error());

            if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

            $tipo = trim($row["tipo"]);

            if ($tipo == "MT")
            {

                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                  print_r($row);
```

Tampoco me muestra un error en esa linea del código... alguien sabe cual puede ser mi error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba de poner en el while esto:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
}
```

Además porque pones un die() en la variable $result, teoricamente la variable die() deberias, de ponerlo si no se conecta a la base de datos, es decir, en la variable $conexion. Te propongo una posible solucion, y es esta estructura, que yo utilizo y siempre me va bien:

```
<?php
   $conexion = new mysqli("localhost","user","passwd","DB");
   if(!conexion){
      die("error DB: ".$conexion->connect_error);
   }
   $consulta = "SELECT * FROM table";
   $result = $conexion->query($consulta);
   if($result->num_rows > 0){
      while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
        if($row['tipo'] == "MT"){
              print_r($row['tipo']);
        }
      }
   }
?>
```

Lo que tendría que hacer este fragmento de condigo, es que si en el campo tipo de la DB hay una celda con el contenido "MT" lo que hará es imprimir todos los valores que hay en el campo "tipo", si en lo que quieres es imprimir toda la base de datos tendrías que reemplazar ´print_r($row['tipo'])´ a esto:

```
echo "tipo: ".$row['tipo'];
echo "campo2: ".$row['campo2'];
...
```

Así todas las que quiereas. Obviamente puedes personalizar la manera en como quieres que se vea.

Comment: Hay error de sintaxis aquí: `if(!conexion){` debes ponerle la `$` a la variable: **`if(!$conexion){`**

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo por tu respuesta, me sirvio en un 80%, lo modifique un poco y me funciono a la perfeccion, asi lo deje yo:           $result = mysql_query($sSQL, $conexion) or die(mysql_error());

            $numero_filas = mysql_num_rows($result);

             if($numero_filas > 0){

                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

                  if($row['tipo'] == "MT"){

Comment: Me alegro de que mi respuesta te haya ayudado a solucionar el problema